# Why does list comprehension closure throw `NameError` in python 3 but not in python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While upgrading code from Py2 to Py3, I ran into an oddity I can't quite explain.  A list comprehension in a class definition can reference other class level variables in both python 2 and 3 as part of the `for` clause.  However, if the variables are part of the `if` clause they throw a `NameError` in python 3 but work just fine in python 2.

I found a few related questions but they don't quite seem to explain the issue.  [Dictionary class attribute that refers to other class attributes in the definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257783/dictionary-class-attribute-that-refers-to-other-class-attributes-in-the-definiti) is a similar issue in lambdas, but doesn't seem to be python version dependant.  Additonally [Why am I getting a NameError in list comprehension (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903399/why-am-i-getting-a-nameerror-in-list-comprehension-python), but has to do with scope in a debugger rather than a class.

The following code works fine on python 2.7.16, but fails on Python 3.7.4:

```
class A(object):
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [n for n in a if n in a]

print(A.b)
```

In python 2 I get:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

In python 3 I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list_comprehension_closure.py", line 3, in <module>
    class A(object):
  File "list_comprehension_closure.py", line 5, in A
    b = [n for n in a if n in a]
  File "list_comprehension_closure.py", line 5, in <listcomp>
    b = [n for n in a if n in a]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

However, the following works fine in both python 2 and 3 and the only difference is the `if` clause:

```
class A(object):
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [n for n in a]

print(A.b)
```

Additionally, the following works in both python 2 and 3 and the only difference is that the comprehension is defined outside of a `class` block:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [n for n in a if n in a]

print(b)
```

I know there were some changes to closures and list comprehensions in Python 3, but I am not seeing anything that explains this difference.

Edit:
For clarity, I am not looking for a work around.  As demonstrated by my last example, I'm aware that moving the variables outside of the class scope I can resolve the issue.  However, what I am looking for is an explanation for why this behavior was changed in python 3.

Comment: Copy the python 2 code to your python 3 file and run it again

Comment: @U10-Forward While it would have surprised me to find a significant change in either version of python in the 10 minutes since posting, for the sake of being a good sport I have run identical code in python 2 and 3 again and got the same result:

```
> cat list_comprehension_closure.py 


class A(object):
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [n for n in a if n in a]

print(A.b)

> python2.7 list_comprehension_closure.py 
[1, 2, 3]

> python3.7 list_comprehension_closure.py 
...
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: @hunzter Thanks, I didn't see that question in my search.  However, it doesn't quite address the issue.  The  explanation makes sense as to why the first example where I reference `a` in the if clause fails.  I may be missing something in the bytecode decomposition, but my reading of that would seem to suggest that my second example where `a` is referenced only in the `for` clause *should fail* in python 3, but it doesn't.

Comment: @hunzter, actually on more careful reading, the linked question does address why my second example works.  "There's one part of a comprehension or generator expression that executes in the surrounding scope, regardless of Python version. That would be the expression for the outermost iterable."

Answer (score 2):

To me this look like an issue of inappropriate scope for the variable `a`.  The following works by putting `a` in the higher scope:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
class A(object):
    b = [n for n in a if n in a]

print(A.b)
```

Comment: I understand there are ways around this, and in fact for the sake of getting the code working I took a variant of the first approach you are suggesting.  Your second approach does not work in either python version as `A` is not finished being defined when it is referenced.  In both python 2 and 3 it throws `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`  However, I am trying to understand the *why* of what changed between python 2 and 3 that would explain the difference in behavior.

Comment: I removed the second part since you're right, it doesn't work. I must not have cleared everything first.  I don't have an answer for why.